# Java How to get millisecond part of current time and not from 1970

Tags: java, time, milliseconds

I am using System.currentTimeMillis() to get number of milliseconds since 1970, I can get current Hour, Minute and seconds using following:

```
Long currTimeInMilliSec =   System.currentTimeMillis()
int h = (((currTimeInMilliSec / 1000) / 3600 ) % 24)
int m = (((currTimeInMilliSec / 1000) / 60) % 60)
int s = ((currTimeInMilliSec / 1000) % 60)
```

How can I calculate millisecond of Current time (not from 1970), because if I use int ms = currentTimeInMilliSec that would be number of milliseconds since 1970.

Note: For some reason, I need to use only currentTimeMillis function to calculate and I don't want to use other functions or external libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `currentTimeInMilliSec % 1000`.

You can also think about it this way: it works for the same reason that `int m = totalMinutes % 60` works, and you have already found that this works.

But a more detailed explanation is as follows: `N % M` gives you a number from `0` to `M - 1`. So, you will always get a number of milliseconds from `0` to `999`. And each time your `currentTimeInMilliSec` advances by one, this number also advances by one, but if this number ever exceeds `999`, it warps around to `0`, which is the exact behaviour that you want.

Comment: Explain why this answers the question.

Comment: I also thought of this as answer but I was not sure, however can you please explain it.

Comment: `N % M` gives you a number from `0` to `M - 1`.  So, you will always get a number of milliseconds from `0` to `999`.   And each time your `currentTimeInMilliSec` advances by one, this number also advances by one, but if this number ever exceeds `999`, it warps around to `0`, which is the exact behaviour that you want.

Comment: Thanks, I think it makes sense but I will mark as correct after a little bit testing.

Comment: Sure, by all means, do your testing first. In the mean time, let me mention that you can also think about it this way: it works for the same reason that `int m = totalMinutes % 60` works, and you have already found that this works.

Answer (score 0):

This question is about arithmetics and not programming, but here:

Given a specific time `t`, the number of ms from `t` to current time is:

`System.currentTimeMillis() + ([midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC] - t)`.

Now all you have to do is decide on a unit of measurement and convert all the abstractly represented times aboves to it and perform the calculation.

**Example**:

If `t` is `midnight, January 1, 1960 UTC`, then

`[midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC] - t = [number of ms in 10 years]`

and the number of ms from `t` to now is

`System.currentTimeMillis() + [number of ms in 10 years]`.

Comment: Sorry can you please explain a bit more, I couldn't relate much to what I am looking for.

Comment: @user1809095 You said `I am using System.currentTimeMillis() to get number of milliseconds since 1970... How can I calculate millisecond of Current time (not from 1970)`. I gave you the calculation for how to calculate the number of milliseconds not from 1970 to current time.